# Customising Circlular seek arc to place bitmaps at given progress levels

Tags: java, android, geometry, drawing, android-bitmap

**Current**

[image]

**Exprected**

[image]
am looking to achieve  a better result than the one in the picture,
situation.
 Given a progress value X i want to get the x and y cordinates of the progress so that i can plot a flag on around the [circular seekarc](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAAahUKEwjr45W6y4HJAhUBdx4KHbdqAOw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FTriggertrap%2FSeekArc&usg=AFQjCNHir42XnEF4owgPGycpQf3xEks6Xg&sig2=Ph-iy38W5H0KQuMPAr7oQA&bvm=bv.106923889,d.ZWU).

```
    for (int i = 0; i < positionList.size(); i++) {

        xPost = (float)(mArcRect.centerX() + mArcRadius* Math.cos(Math.toRadians(calculatePointerAngle((positionList.get(i).getPosition()+270)))));
        yPost = (float) (mArcRect.centerY() + mArcRadius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(calculatePointerAngle((positionList.get(i).getPosition()+270)))));


        setflagX(xPost);
        setflagxY(yPost);
        points.add(new Points(xPost, yPost));


        // }
    }
```

After which i use a custom class to draw the flags

.....
`

```
 @Override
      public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //Draw the flag

    final Resources res = getResources();

// while (coordinates.iterator().hasNext()){
for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.size(); i++) {
    if (i == 0) {

        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.ic_flag_red);

        canvas.drawBitmap(bm, coordinates.get(i).getX(),      coordinates.get(i).getY(), null);
        } else {

            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.ic_flag_blue);

            canvas.drawBitmap(bm, coordinates.get(i).getX(), coordinates.get(i).getY(), null);

        }
    }



}`
```

Any suggestion on how to fix the off set... am okay with the point bing outside the circle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me what you do is correct, but you're drawing the bitmap wrong.

The bitmap draws from (left, top) to (left + width, right + height) and you don't account for that.

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bm, 
    coordinates.get(i).getX() - bm.getWidth() / 2,
    coordinates.get(i).getY() - bm.getHeight() / 2, null);
```

Should fix your problem